# Array into HashTable

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

I want to create hashtable which would take each String from my array and assign it to unique integer value. My array is read from file and assigned to array like this:

```
public void readFile() throws Exception{

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("words.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String strLine;
    wordsList = new String[getNumberOfLines()];   

    for (int j = 0; j < wordsList.length; j++){
    wordsList[j] = br.readLine();

    }
    in.close();
}
```

Using this array I wrote method to create hash table like this:

```
String currentWord;
private Hashtable <String,Integer> wordsHashTable;
LinesReader lr = new LinesReader();
int i;
String[] listOfWords;

public boolean insertValues() throws Exception{
    for (i=0; i<lr.getNumberOfLines();i++){
        lr.readFile();
        listOfWords = lr.returnsWordList();
        currentWord = listOfWords[i];
        wordsHashTable.put(currentWord, i+1);
    }
    return wordsHashTable.isEmpty(); //testing purposes only
}
```

It throws NullPointer exception at line: wordsHashTable.put(currentWord, i+1);
Any ideas where I messed up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize your `wordsHashTable` with an instance of the class:

```
private Hashtable <String,Integer> wordsHashTable = new Hashtable<>();
```

**However**, do note that the `Hashtable` class is obsolete; you should use `java.util.HashMap` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe it was such a silly mistake and thanks for hint (our lecturer said we should use hashtable in our assignment, but will know for future reference)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your hash table. You forgot to initialize it.

```
 private Hashtable <String,Integer> wordsHashTable = new Hashtable<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialized the `Hashtable'.

```
private Hashtable <String,Integer> wordsHashTable = new Hashtable <String,Integer>();
```

will fix it.

However, I would recommend you to move to something more modern like a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)